# Order items based on multiple attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a model `ticket` which has the attributes `priority`, `status` and `target_date`

I want to list tickets in ascending order of `priority` and ascending order of `target_date`, and starting with tickets whose `status` is not "resolved".

How can I do this?

`priority` can have the values P1, P2 and P3.

`status` can be "Created", "In Progress" or "Resolved"

Answer (score 0):

You can use *case* statement for status and mix it with *priority* and *target_date* in the *order* method.

The scope might look like this:

```
scope :ordered_by_status_priority_target_date, -> {
    order("case status
           when 'resolved' then 2
           else 1
           end, priority, target_date")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what you are searching for.

```
 Ticket.where.not(status: :resolved).order(priority: :asc, target_date: :desc)
```

or you can omit the `asc` on the first instance and have it sorted asc for the priority by default and that would be

```
  Ticket.where.not(status: :resolved).order(:priority, target_date: :desc)
```